# Decode spanner row fields to nested structs golang

Tags: go, struct, google-cloud-spanner

I have two structs

```
type Row struct{
  ID string 
  Status string
  details Details
}

type Details struct{
  SessionID string
  Location string
  Project string
}
```

And I get data like this

```
Select a.ID, a.Status, b.SessionID, b.Location, b.Project from table1 as a left join table2 as b on a.ID == b.SessionID
```

Now, to get all the select info in a row I need to change the struct and add the fields in it instead of a struct(Details) which is essentially duplicating fields in Row and Details (which I need for other purpose as well).

```
type Row struct{
  ID string 
  Status string
  SessionID string
  Location string
  Project string
}

r := Row{}
spanner.row.ToStruct(&r) // this works
```

but is there a simplified way to get the data without having to duplicate the fields in the struct or specifying each field in spanner.row.Column? I read that spanner.row.ToStruct does not support destination struct to have a struct as field as that's not a supported column type, but what's a better workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have not worked on the google cloud scanner directly but from the Go language point of view, How about embedding the Structs?

i.e.:

```golang
type Row struct{
  ID string 
  Status string
  Details
}

type Details struct{
  SessionID string
  Location string
  Project string
}

r := Row{}
spanner.row.ToStruct(&r)
```

Comment: This suggestion should work. You can create a combined struct and pass that into the `Row.ToStruct` method.